# How does one maintain session when using Google sign-in for websites?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js, google-signin, login-control

I have a Hapi backend for my website where on the front-end, a user logs in on my website using his Google account and then I do the usual process of sending the `id_token` to the server to decrypt and verify his `Sub` field to authorize the user.

The problem arises when the user logs out of Gmail or Google apps on some other tab or window, **the user is logged out of my website by Google** *on the front end* and I am unable to control or know it (at the backend).

This renders my session maintenance useless at the server as the user is forcibly logged out on the front end.

I saw that Stack Overflow has (obviously) taken care of this and even when I log out of my Gmail, I still stay logged in on SO. This is exactly what I want for my app wherein I am able to control the session at the client-side even when he or she logs out. What do I need to do?

Comment: use google's oauth just for verification of the user? keep the actual database used for authentication on your own server

Comment: how come your user is logged out of your frontend? What do you mean "by Google"? It is your site, you should be in control I guess, or am I missing something?

Comment: how do you maintain the session on the frontend anyway?